# OSX : Safari restart automatically after it is closed. How to resolve that

Tags: macos, security, safari

i downloaded a malicious software about “coinhive” by mistake. then, Safari start automatically and cannot be closed. How to reslove this problem?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have a malware. Coinhive is not really a virus by itself : it is a JavaScript cryptocurrency miner. Since Coinhive is browser-based, your malware is probably hidden in an extension or somewhere else.

Start by disabling dubious browser extensions and then run an antivirus, like [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac/).